# Setting the java.library.path using a BAT file on windows 7

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I am trying to set the java.library.path to the current directory using a BAT-file.

Heres what I use:

```
java -Djava.library.path=%cd%
pause
```

However it does not work. The command promt just returns this:

```
C:\Users\Johan-bar\Desktop\Arbete>java -Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Johan-bar\De
sktop\Arbete
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)

where options include:
    -client       to select the "client" VM
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -hotspot      is a synonym for the "client" VM  [deprecated]
                  The default VM is client.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose[:class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -jre-no-restrict-search
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                    see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument

    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image

C:\Users\Johan-bar\Desktop\Arbete>pause
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Isn't the error message clear? You are missing a required parameter to the java command.

Comment: I do not understand what is missing

Comment: You are missing either a classname or `-jar jarfile` as stated in the first 4 lines of the error.

Comment: I have a jarfile; I've tried this: java -jar -Djava.library.path="C:\Users\Johan-bar\Desktop\Arbete" myJar        and it returns "unable to access jarfile myJar". Why can't it access it? it's in the same directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is not well-formed, as stated by the error-message.  Since you are trying to run a jar-file, you should specify it like this:

```
java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
```

In your case that would be:

```
java -Djava.library.path=%cd% -jar myJar
```

Note: The reference to the `jar` should contain the extension as well.  If your jar is actually called `myJar`, consider changing it to have the `.jar` extension.  If not, add `.jar` to above mentioned command.

Comment: I'm not trying to run the jar-file. I just want to add the folder to the java.library.path, because later on I will run an applet which will load a library.

Comment: You should have mentioned this in your question then, it changes the situation completely.  Your question would be how to specify `java.library.path` when running an applet.  Starting a Java process with that property specified will make the property known only to the process you start.  I have no idea on how this should be done for applets.

Comment: I need to clarify again: you first run a batch file, -then- run the html-file which loads an applet. So its not when running; its before you run the applet :p

Answer (score 0):

You have probably forgotten the quotes `"`

Try this:

```
java "-Djava.library.path=C:\Users\Johan-bar\Desktop\Arbete"
```

Comment: Then the problem is something else